# If I rush does my salah become Qaza?

Tags: salat, salat-qada

Actually I have rushed through many of my salats or at least prayed faster than normal. So do I have to read these salats qaza again or do I ask forgiveness from Allah and repent and try not to do it again?

Comment: I indeed admire what you have asked. Since occasionally I ask myself what will be the result of such Salahs, and actually will they be accepted or not. / Of course apparently it would be accepted, but decrease its thawab, but I'm still looking for a nice answer too, in order to be more certain about that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No actually. Have attention and consideration during pray is emphasized, but it's not a vital or necessary part of it.

It's better you ask God's forgiveness and try more concentration on your prays.

If you say words exactly and motions accurately, speed is not a factor!

Comment: you can have a better response by adding a hadith or ... But anyway, in my opinion: your answer deserve +1 as a right brief answer which can convey the right way to the questioner. Good luck mate.

Answer (score -2):

You need to learn what prayer really means (coming nearer to Allah swt by purifying one's soul.

Please read Soul and Spirit

http://heliwave.com/Soul.and.Spirit.pdf

to understand the difference between then and in sha Allah understand the meaning of the rituals especially sending salaams to our Prophet )pbuh+f), ourselves, 3ibaad Allah al-saliheen, and all angels around us at the end of the prayer.

Remember in every prayer unit (ruk3a), we do two prostrations (sijoods) to simulate Death/Life/Death/Life as stated in Quran 2:28
كَيْفَ تَكْفُرُونَ بِٱللَّهِ وَكُنتُمْ أَمْوَٰتًۭا فَأَحْيَٰكُمْ ۖ ثُمَّ يُمِيتُكُمْ ثُمَّ يُحْيِيكُمْ ثُمَّ إِلَيْهِ تُرْجَعُونَ {٢٨}
002:028 How can you be unfaithful to Allah, [seeing that] you were lifeless and He gave you life, then He will make you die and then bring you to life, and then you will be brought back to Him?

God >

Comment: Hello and welcome to [islam.se]. Good words out there, but they fail to answer the question, i.e. *
If I rush does my salah become Qaza?*. Please go through [answer] and the [tour] page.